# Run textarea to iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to run an HTML, CSS and JavaScript code written by the user in a `textarea` on an `iframe` in the page, something like jsFiddle. I tried using this for the HTML and CSS:

```
$(".runBtn").on("click", function(){
$(".Result > iframe").contents().find('body').html("<style>" + $('.CSS > textarea').val() + '</style>' + $(".HTML > textarea").val());})
```

But it doesn't seem to work. And I still haven't got a clue on how to run the javascript on it.

Comment: `$("runBtn")` should probably be `$('#runBtn')`. Does that look like `.html()` to you? I see part of a `</style>` tag which shouldn't go in the `.find('body')`. `<style>` goes in the `<head>`. Please use external CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Comunication with iframe is tricky and You should not be using it like that. There is API for communication with iframe no mater it is from site to iframe or iframe to site. I didn't use it for a long time so i can't give you some good examples but You have everything You need on  [1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)

it goes down to that you send a message trough that API to iframe with some payload, and inside of him You have event listener to that message event. when you receive it, render html from payload.

Answer (score 0):

`$("runBtn")` is looking for a elements that are a tag `<runBtn>` that most likely doesn't exist. If element has an id you need a proper id prefix

```
$("#runBtn")
```

As for your html you haven't created a proper `<style>` tag. Also not clear where the textarea is in relation to iframe (inside iframe or outside). If it is inside you need to use `find()` within iframe contents to access it